# Manifolds and auto-encoder latent space

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, machine-learning

(I apologise in advance for a naive and/or misplaced question)

I don’t have a math background, rather robotics and self-taught ML, but I am trying to learn more and understand some abstract concepts or at least get a clearer intuition (i.e. forgive my poor terminology use).

I am reading into (Riemannian) manifolds and obtaining geodesics as distance metrics on manifolds.

What still confuses me is the following:

Most examples explaining (Riemannian) manifolds involve either low-dimensional and ideal examples (e.g. circles and spheres) or very abstract equations. I got some intuition from this blogpost (http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/manifolds/) on how to get the metric, but I am not sure how can this be done on some arbitrary manifold.

To be more specific: How to define a manifold based on some data samples? As I understand, I first need to fit some (probability) function to the data I have, and this function needs to be smooth/differentiable so I can get the tangent space. From there I can estimate geodesics/metric etc.

Moreover, how can I assure that the fitted function actually gives me a manifold?

Comment: What makes you think that a smooth manifold can be somehow associated to a finite set of data for a machine learning process?

Comment: In ML we try to fit some parameterized (probability) function to the data, and we assume that this is how the data was generated. So if this function is smooth can it be considered a manifold?